# Calculate number of words in an ArrayList while some words are on the same line

Tags: java

I'm trying to calculate how many words an ArrayList contains. I know how to do this if every words is on a separate line, but some of the words are on the same line, like:

```
hello there
blah
cats dogs
```

So I'm thinking I should go through every entry and somehow find out how many words the current entry contains, something like:

```
    public int numberOfWords(){
    for(int i = 0; i < arraylist.size(); i++) {
        int words = 0;
        words = words + (number of words on current line);
    //words should eventually equal to 5
    }
return words;
}
```

Am I thinking right?

Comment: first split with line and then each line with space.

Comment: How did the `words` end up having spaces between them to begin with ? You can use `String.split()` but may be there is a better way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should declare and instantiate `int words` outside of the loop the `int` is not reassign during every iteration of the loop.  You can use the `for..each` syntax to loop through the list, which will eliminate the need to `get()` items out of the list.  To handle multiple words on a line `split` the `String` into an `Array` and count the items in the `Array`.

```
public int numberOfWords(){
    int words = 0;
    for(String s:arraylist) {         
      words += s.split(" ").length;
    }
    return words;
}
```

**Full Test**

```
public class StackTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
        arraylist.add("hello there");
        arraylist.add("blah");
        arraylist.add("   cats    dogs");
        arraylist.add(" ");
        arraylist.add(" ");
        arraylist.add(" ");

        int words = 0;
        for(String s:arraylist) {
            s = s.trim().replaceAll(" +", " "); //clean up the String
            if(!s.isEmpty()){ //do not count empty strings
               words += s.split(" ").length;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(words);
    }
}
```

Comment: Beware of lines with spaces! This will give you "1": `System.out.println("    ".split(" ").length);` (there should be multiple spaces inside the split regex, but I can't convince the autoformat in SO to show it

Comment: @Miquel  I didn't think about that, new update uses `trim()`, thanks!

Comment: Actually I'm looking into something now. Turns out this `System.out.println("     ".trim().split(" ").length);` gives you 1 while this `System.out.println("     ".split(" ").length);` gives you 0

Comment: Also, `System.out.println("a___b___c ".trim().split("_").length);` gives you 7

Comment: @Miquel Actually `trim()` doesn't even help `s.trim().split().length ==1` when `s==" "`, I had to check for `" "` within a conditional, do you know a better approach?

Comment: Try this instead: `System.out.println("a___b___c ".split("_+").length);` I'm replacing the spaces with _ due to the stackoverflow autoformat

Comment: @Miquel `System.out.println("".split(" ").length);//prints 1`  Didn't expect that behavior

Comment: @Miquel Updated.  I think this handles it however I had to use the conditional, I'm sure a slick regex could take care of this.

Answer (score 1):

Should looks like this:

```
public int numberOfWords(){
    int words = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < arraylist.size(); i++) {
        words = words + (number of words on current line);
    //words should eventually equal to 5
    }
return words;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help you .

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
public class LineWord {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        File           f        = new File("C:\\Users\\MissingNumber\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Puzzlecode\\src\\com\\test\\test.txt");    // Creating the File passing path to the constructor..!!
        BufferedReader br       = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));    //
        String         strLine  = " ";
        String         filedata = "";

        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            filedata += strLine + " ";
        }

        StringTokenizer stk   = new StringTokenizer(filedata);
        List <String>  token = new ArrayList <String>();

        while (stk.hasMoreTokens()) {
            token.add(stk.nextToken());
        }

        //Collections.sort(token);
        System.out.println(token.size());
        br.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

So you'll red data from a file in this case and store them in a list after tokenizing them , just count them , If you just want to get input from the console use the Bufferedreader , tokenize them , separating with space , put in list , simple get size .

Hope you got what you are looking for .